# Minimizing the surface area with a constant volume

Tags: calculus, geometry, optimization, maxima-minima

I want to minimize the surface area of a rectangular prism, with a constant volume. The dimensions of the prism is $25 \text{ cm} \times 8 \text{ cm} \times 8 \text{ cm}$. If it is "flattened out" [with the top face not included], then the dimensions of the "flattened out" prism is $41\text{ cm} \times 24 \text{ cm}$.

Then, $l = 41 - 2c$, $w = 24 - 2c$, and $h = c$. When I use the formula to get the surface area and differentiate with respect to $c$, all $c$ terms vanish. What did I do wrong?

---

The process that I need to do is differentiation. I think it will be a minimum if $l = w = h$ using AM-GM, but this will not be counted.

---

Edit: I noticed that the only values of $c$ satisfying $c(41 - 2c)(24 - 2c) = 1600$ are $\left\{8, \frac{49 - \sqrt{1601}}{2}, \frac{49 + \sqrt{1601}}{2}\right\}$. Since $0 \leqslant c \leqslant 12$, then the only values are the first two in the list. When I substituted the second value to the formula for the surface area, it is approximately $1675.906\,\mathrm{cm}^{2}$. Then, the minimum surface area must be $728\,\mathrm{cm}^{2}$. Is this correct?

---

Edit [March 03, 2021]: $c$, $24 - 2c$, and $41 - 2c$ is now ignored. Dimensions are now free to take any form satisfying the constraints, accepted answer.

Comment: The "flattened out" surface has nothing to do with your problem. Instead, there could be some constraint you didn't mention. Has the base to be a square, or not?.

Comment: The only constraint is the volume, where it must be constant. The "flattened out" surface that I mentioned is for me to make the values of $l$, $w$, and $h$ as $c$ changes.

Comment: If you haven't any constraint other then volume ($V=1600$), then you can solve for $$l={1600\over hw}$$ and express surface area as a function of $h$ and $w$.

Comment: The solutions become more complicated as I use your given equation, because this will become a quintic equation, if my solution is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question is to find dimensions of a rectangular box, with constant volume of $1600$, that minimizes the surface area of the box. The box is closed on top.

Surface area $S = 2l w + 2 l h + 2 w h$

$V = 1600 = lwh \implies h = \frac{1600}{wl}$

So, $S = 2lw + \frac{3200}{w} + \frac{3200}{l}$.

Now take partial derivative wrt $w$ and $l$ and equate to zero to find $w, l, h$ that minimizes surface area.

$\displaystyle S'_w = 2l - \frac{3200}{w^2} = 0 \implies l = \frac{1600}{w^2}$

$\displaystyle S'_l = 2w - \frac{3200}{l^2} = 0 \implies w = \frac{1600}{l^2}$

Solving both, $\displaystyle l = w = 4 \sqrt[3]{25}$.
Then use this to find value of $h$ and you should get a cube.

Comment: What I mean with the "top face not included" is that it is not included in the "flattened out" box, not in the computations.

Comment: ok I just edited

Comment: I just realized that we are still not allowed to use partial derivatives, since it is not part of our curriculum.

Comment: When we are not allowed to take partial derivative, we keep one of them constant and take derivative. It comes to the same thing but in the beginning before partial derivative is taught, that is how you are supposed to write and do.

Comment: I know how to take partial derivatives, but we are not allowed to do it because it will not be part of our lesson. So I need to explain the partial differentiation in a way to make it not look like partial differentiation, right?

Comment: that is correct, I can edit if you want

Comment: No, thanks. I can do it already.

Comment: is my edit also correct?

Comment: No $780$ is not correct. You should get $820$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120481/discussion-between-soupless-and-math-lover).

Comment: Is it possible to solve this problem without partial derivatives, by using substitution to reduce the objective function to a single-variable function, and find the minimum of that function using graphical methods? Posted separate question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4754989/solve-area-minimization-problem-given-its-dual-volume-maximization-problem-for-l